# php MySQL csv output with WHERE LIKE %%

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 from table');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
?>
```

is work but how to use "where field1 like %%" in result

Comment: ya i find solution '%something%' REPLACE WITH 'something%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT field1,field2,field3 from table where field1 like '%something%'");
```

REPLACE

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT field1,field2,field3 from table where field1 like 'something%'");
```

JUST REMOVE FIRST
`%`

FINALLY WORKS

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test');
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT field1,field2,field3 from table where field1 like 'something%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've completely understood the question.

If you want to query the database and generate a csv from the results returned where each row in the csv has field1 like [something] then it would be better to just include the condition directly in the query:

```
$queryStr = "select field1, field2, field3 from table where field1 like '%something%'";
$rows = mysql_query($queryStr);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

This way you don't return more information than needed.

That aside, mysql_* functions are deprecated and it would probably be a good idea to use mysqli.

Comment: $queryStr = "select field1, field2, field3 from table where field1 like '%something%'";

Comment: with out "where field1 like '%something%'" work fine